# How to post only text to wall Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I tried

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
```

this

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")

             .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                            .build();

         shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

but for this method setContentUrl is needed, if I delete setContentUrl then post doesn't allow to publish. 
But I need only text to post on the wall. How to do it?

Comment: The user have to type the text. You are not allowed to specify the text

Answer (score 3):

Facebook share doesn't support text. You can only share link and that will show the  text from that page with your link in Facebook.

also Facebook Policy for user message says to avoid pre-fill the user message parameter with any content the user didn't enter themselves, even if they can edit or delete that content before sharing. This applies to posts, comments, photo captions, and photo album captions.

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) to policy page